# Please help with watermelon

Tags: diagnosis

Can someone please help me tell me what’s the best soil and fertilizer for water melons? I have heard sand and all kinds of stuff to help my water melons get big. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us about how you are growing them now?  What is the soil like, if you have fertilized, etc.

Comment: **Where on the planet also matters.** And you have not stated that. As far as I know it's either not possible or practical (greenhouse, extra lights, etc...) to grow big melons where I live (~43°N). Those are all shipped here from closer to the equator. We can grow little ones if everything works out in a particular year - some years we can't get any useable ones. Just plain not the right climate for them.

Comment: I agree with others that we need more details. Location, type of soil, type of melon planted etc.

Comment: If you want answers to “what am I doing wrong”, it would help immensely if you add what you are doing. Please see the other comments and [edit] your post.